# Questions about SVD, Singular Value Decomposition

Tags: math, matrix, vector

I am not a mathematician, so I need to understand what SVD does and WHY more than how it works exactly from the math perspective. (I understand at least what is the decomposition though).

[This guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P5mlg91as1c) on youtube gave the only human explanation of SVD saying, that the U matrix maps "user to concept correlation" Sigma matrix defines the strength of each concept, and V maps "movie to concept correlation" given that initial matrix M has users in the rows, and movie (ratings) in the columns.

He also mentioned two concept specifically "sci fi" and "romance" movies. See the picture below.

[image]

My questions are:

1. How SVD knows the number of concepts. He as human mentioned two - sci fi, and romance, but in reality in resulting matrices are 3 concepts. (for example matrix U - that one with blue titles - has 3 columns not 2).
2. How SVD knows what is the concept after all. I mean, what If i shuffle the columns randomly how SVD then knows what is sci fi, what is romance. I mean, I suppose there is no rule, group the concepts together in the column order. What if scifi movie is the first and last one? and not first 3 columns in the initial matrix M?
3. What is the practical usage of either U, Sigma or V matrices? (Except that you can multiply them to get the initial matrix M)
4. Is there also any other possible human explanation of SVD than the guy up provided, or it is the only one possible function? Matrices of correlations.

Comment: These are all great questions, and I can tell you have already put some substantial thought into it. However, it's off topic for this forum; try stats.stackexchange.com or ds.stackexchange.com instead. The short answer is that SVD is really only about linear algebra, and this business of identifying some vectors with mental concepts is fanciful handwaving at best. That said, it's kind of useful. My advice is to try to study the SVD apart from any specific application, then go to applications. Hope this helps.

Comment: @RobertDodier btw there is really some magery because, if I tried to shuffle the columns (at least it seems) that the correlation of users to concept stays same, and strenght of the concepts aswell.. so in some terms it really identifies the concepts it seems, even if you shuffle the columns as you want.. that is quite magical then. only problem probably is, if you don't know what are the concepts in the columns. but that doesn't matter maybe from view of ML perspective.

Answer (score 1):

As was pointed out in the comments you may well get better explanations elsewhere. However since the question is still open, here is my tuppence worth.

Throughout I'll suppose that A is mxn where m>=n, ie that A has more rows than columns.

First of all there are many forms of the SVD, differing in the sizes of the matrices. They all share the fundamental properties that

```
A = U*S*V'
S is diagonal 
U and V have orthogonal columns (ie U'*U = I, V'*V = I)
```

Perhaps the most useful from a theoretical point of view is the 'full fat' svd where we have that U is mxm, S is mxn and V is nxn. However this has rather a lot of elements that don't really contribute to A. For example S being diagonal we can write

```
S = ( S1 )  (where S1 is nxn )
    ( 0  )
```

If we divide up U into

```
U = ( U1 U2) (where U1 is mxn and U2 is (mx(m-n)))
```

Then its straightforward to calculate that

```
U*S = U1*S1
```

and so we can throw away the last m-n columns of U and the last m-n rows of S, and still recover A.

Moreover some of the diagonal elements of S1 may be 0; suppose in fact that p<n of them are non zero. Then we can write

```
S1 = ( S2 0)
     ( 0  0)
```

And arguing as above for U and analogously for V' we can in fact throw away all but the first p columns of U and all of S but S2, and all but the first p rows of V, and still recover A.

This latter is the form of SVD ('thin') in your question:

```
U is mxp
S is pxp
V' is pxm
```

where p is the number of non-zero singular values of A. This is my answer to your 1.

By convention the elements of S decrease as you move down the diagonal. To achieve this the routine that calculates the svd in effect works with a version of A with shuffled columns. This shuffling is undone by incorporating the shuffle in the U and V' output. This is my answer to your 2: however you shuffle A, it will be in effect shuffled again to ensure that the singular values decrease down the diagonal.

I struggle to answer 3, because I suspect that our ideas of 'practical' are rather different.

One thing that I think practical is to find simpler approximations to A. The reconstruction of A can be written

```
A = Sum{ 1<=i<=p | U[i]*S[i]*V[i]' }
```

where the S[i] are the diagonal elements of S, U[i] are the columns of U and V[i] those of V

We might want to use a simpler model for A, for example want to simplify it down to just one term. That is, we might wonder how much we would lose by using fewer 'concepts'. The 'thin' svd above has already done this in the sense that it has thrown away all the coluns that make no contribution to A. In an extreme case, we might wonder what we would get if we reduced to just one concept. This approximation is found by  taking just the first term of the sum above. This extends to however many terms -- q say -- we want to allow: we just take the first q terms of the sum above.

I'm sorry, I can't answer 4.

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will check it.